# Unable to locate the external sqlite file within the swift programming

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite

I am new to iOS programming.  I am trying to attach an sqlite database record with my new iOS programming.

I have added my sqlite file via CopyBundle resources 
But through programming I am unable to locate my file and its always failing.  Kindly help

The filename contains the value 'KEERTHANAIGAL.sqlite" passed from AppDelegate file

Following is my programming

```
class Util: NSObject {
class func getPath(fileName: String) -> String {

   let filemanager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()

    let documentDirectoryPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
   let destinationPath = documentDirectoryPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(fileName)
   let sourcePath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("KEERTHANAIGAL", ofType: "sqlite")

    do {
    try filemanager.copyItemAtPath(sourcePath!, toPath: destinationPath)
    }
    catch let error1 as NSError{ print (" OOPS Something went wrong : \(error1)")}

    return destinationPath
}

class func copyFile(fileName: NSString) {
    let dbPath: String = getPath(fileName as String)
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    if !fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(dbPath) {

        let documentsURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().resourceURL
        let fromPath = documentsURL!.URLByAppendingPathComponent(fileName as String)

        var error : NSError?
        do {
            try fileManager.copyItemAtPath(fromPath.path!, toPath: dbPath)
        } catch let error1 as NSError {
            error = error1
        }
        let alert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        if (error != nil) {
            alert.title = "Error Occured"
            alert.message = error?.localizedDescription
        } else {
            alert.title = "Successfully Copy"
            alert.message = "Your database copy successfully"
        }
        alert.delegate = nil
        alert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        alert.show()
    }
}
```

The below code tries to read the database at path

```
@IBAction func getSong(sender: AnyObject) {
    let KeerthanaigalDB = FMDatabase(path: databasePath as String)
    if KeerthanaigalDB.open()
    {
        let querySQL = "SELECT NEXT SONGNAME, SONGLYRICS FROM KEERTHANAIGAL.DB"
        let results:FMResultSet? = KeerthanaigalDB.executeQuery(querySQL, withArgumentsInArray: nil)
        if results?.next() == true
        {
            songTitle.text = results?.stringForColumn("SONGNAME")
            songLyrics.text = results?.stringForColumn("SONGLYRICS")
            status.text = "Record Found"

        }
        else{
            status.text = "Record Not Found"
            songTitle.text = " "
            songLyrics.text = " "

        }
        KeerthanaigalDB.close()
    }
    else
    {
        print("Error: \(KeerthanaigalDB.lastErrorMessage())")
    }
```

And the code always goes to the 'Record not found' clause and the debugger says "no such table: KEERTHANAIGAL.DB" (I get the same message when I mention "KEERTHANAIGAL" without DB

how do I view the DB file?  I copied only the sqlite file created by Firefox sqlite manager

Comment: Could you explain "is always failing" further? What's the current behaviour of the program?

Comment: HI, The code was able to recognize that KEERTHANAIGAL.SQLITE exists at path (It gave me a message that file already exists at path), now when I query the database it throws 'no such table'

Comment: later I added the code to viewDidLoad function by defining the databasePath and it worked finally :)